# How 'dict_values' can be convert to integers in a list?

Tags: python, list, class, oop, dictionary

I'm new in Python, and didn't find previous questions that describe the issue I'm asking for. Thank you.

1) My first question is, why the type that I get here is not a real List ?  (the  [ ] in the output, looks like a list but it's not, as you can see in the line below).

2) How can I convert the values in this 'dict_values' to integers inside a List (to make some calculations later) ?

```
print(list(node_list[j].neighbors.values()))
print(type(node_list[j].neighbors.values()))
```

The output is:

```
[10, 20, 20, 5, 10]
<class 'dict_values'>
```

Comment: It looks like you've already figured out how to convert it to a list of integers?

Comment: your'e getting a list because you are converting the input to a list, can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: No, I did not figured out yet. How can I add here the rest of the code just in the comment in a readble way ?

Comment: `[10, 20, 20, 5, 10]` <- That's a list of integers. If that's not the output you want, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Well, it works now. I just ignored the type and started with the claculations which haven't work before. Anyway,  the type which shows up is still 'dict_values' Thank you.